# Python Accessing attributes of an object as a dict value

Tags: python, dictionary

suppose I have a `dict` like that:

```
dict = {'people': [<Bob>], 'animals': [<Frank>]}
```

Bob and Frank are two objects with attributes:

```
Bob = MethodForCreateAPerson(){          Frank = MethodForCreateAnimals(){
    name = 'Bob',                            name = 'Frank',
    age = 30,                                age = 6,
    sex = 'm'                                sex = 'w'
}                                         }
```

The Question is:

How can I access Bob's and Frank's attributes when they are values of a `dict`?

In other words, I need to check the attributes of the objects returned from `dict.values()`.

Thanks for help

Comment: What exactly is `[<Bob>]`? A list with an object? An object? A string inside a list?

Comment: Is something like `dict['people'][0].name` not enough? Seems like you have a dictionary from strings to lists of objects.

Comment: [<Bob>] is and object in a list created from a django model,
dict['people'][0].name gives "TypeError: 'BoundField' object does not support indexing"

Comment: This does not look like [tag:python]

Comment: You are getting `TypeError: 'BoundField' object does not support indexing` most probably because you don't have list of objects instead you have single object. Can you confirm?

Comment: Django ad Rest framework, the object bob is created with a serializer.
@GarbageCollector yes

Comment: If you have a single object then you can use `dict['people'].name`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what your structure actually looks like but if your values in your dictionary are lists of objects then the following will work:

```
people = dict['people'] #  get the people list
bob = people[0] #  the first entry in that list is bob
name_of_bob = bob.name #  access the name of bob

also_name_of_bob = dict['people'][0].name #  does the same but in 1 line
```

Accessing the people list like this is probably not what you would like to do in your code though, you would likely want to iterate over all the people like this:

```
for person in dict['people']:
    person_name = person.name
    # do something with the person or the name
```